# "Ветреный" — правильно. Но как объяснить?

Tags: орфография

[Ветренный или ветреный](https://ruslitfak.ru/vetrenyj-ili-vetrennyj-kak-pravilno-pishetsya/)

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как объяснить делающему первые шаги в русском языке правописание слова "ветреный".

Comment: [O строптивом прилагательном **ветреный**](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.59)

Answer (score 4):

Никак. Пусть считает это слово исключением, которое надо запомнить или проверять по словарю. 
На самом деле объяснение есть (исторически это ***отглагольное прилагательное*** от малоупотребительного сейчас глагола ***"ветрить"***), но оно для делающего первые шаги не слишком убедительно. Ибо непонятно.

Comment: А вы уверены, что такой глагол был?

Comment: @Aer "Ветрить"? Так он и сейчас есть, не извольте сомневаться, из словарей еще не выпал окончательно. Да дело не в этом, версия-то не моя. Она известная, и по ссылке у автора вопроса тоже приводится...

Comment: А в каких словарях?

Comment: Да хотя бы в Вики)))

Comment: Или вот (на академике найдено) 
ВЕТРИТЬ
    —-носиться по ветру, сушить на ветру. 
Словарь ветров. — Ленинград: Гидрометеоиздат. Л.З. Прох. 1983. https://veter.academic.ru/2847/%D0%92%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC

Comment: И у Даля есть. Хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Написание слова ***ветреный***   соответствует **общему стандарту правил по этой теме.** Это слово не является исключением, его можно проверить по словарю, но что-либо заучивать или запоминать не требуется.

Решение орфографической задачи для слова ***ветреный***

1) При выборе Н и НН в суффиксах прилагательных прежде всего решается **основной вопрос: это отглагольное или отыменное прилагательное,** так эти варианты имеют разное решение.

2) У нас есть пара ***ветрить — ветер.*** Глагол ***ветрить*** существует только в связанном виде (***обветрить, заветрить***), но это неважно.

Прилагательное ***ветреный*** считается **отглагольным** (**это и есть то единственное, что нужно запомнить**), в нем выделяется **суффикс ЕН** с одной буквой Н (образование от бесприставочного глагола несовершенного вида *ветрить*).

Поэтому мы пишем ***ветреный день, ветреный человек, обветренное лицо, заветренный хлеб*** (о предметах, находящихся под **действием** ветра). **Суффикс ЕНН** пишется при наличии приставки.

3) Но: ***ветер — ветрянОй*** (ветряная мельница, ветряной двигатель). Здесь  **отыменный** суффикс ЯН, образование от существительного (о предметах, где используется сила **ветра**).

Примечание: Такие же пары образуют слова ***масло — маслить***, ***серебро — серебрить***. Например: *серебряный, серебрёный, посеребрённый*.

Answer (score 0):

В приведенной вами статье есть итоговое предложение — на него и нужно ориентироваться.

*А нам надо просто запомнить, что слово **«ветреный»** пишется с одной буквой **«н»**.*

Прилагательное **ве́треный** присутствует **во всех** орфографических словарях. (У меня имеются издания 1938, 1952, 1957, 1996, 2003 годов — "исключительное" слово в них есть.)

В полном академическом справочнике ([Особенности написания отдельных суффиксов. § 45](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=35#pp35)):
*Различаются, с одной стороны, прилагательные **ветреный** и тундреный (ветреная погода, ветреный человек, тундреная растительность и т. п.), где **как исключение** в суффиксе пишется одно **н**.*

Comment: Скажите, Римма, Вы неспроста пишете "вы" с маленькой буквы в ответе или случайно? Просто я привык писать с большой, если обращаюсь к автору, но хотел бы заменить его на маленькую, если это можно оправдать (как в литературных произведениях). Не хочу быть крикливым, если это лишнее. (Вообще, переход на ***вы*** с маленькой у меня не связан с уменьшением уважения.)

Comment: Некоторое время назад в ответах мои **Вы** и **вы** периодически исправляли друг на друга (я даже по этому поводу задала вопрос на Мете). Я теперь делаю так: в комментариях — всегда "Вы" (потому что персонально); в ответе незнакомцу или новичку — "вы" (предназначен для всех пользователей); в ответе Вам или другому постоянному участнику — "Вы". К Вам могу и по имени — когда-то ведь Вы дали на это добро. Могу и покланяться-покивать с большим уважением.

Comment: Хм, я против такого разделения: к постоянным и незнакомцам/новичкам. Не стоит их ставить ниже. Ко мне как раз можете с маленькой. Я тоже пишу с маленькой тем, с кем у меня есть такое, скажем, соглашение, не уважая их меньше, просто для простоты. Например, если пишут мне и другим с маленькой, я делаю вывод, что и они не против, если к ним так же будешь. Никогда с их стороны не воспринимаю это как что-то обидное, просто считаю, что они за простоту.

Comment: ...Потом к старшим, с которыми часто общаюсь и которые ко мне на ты, иногда спрашиваю, можно ли для простоты я буду писать "вы", а кому-то продолжаю писать с большой. Может, кому-то, а то и многим, это покажется неправильным. Во всяком случае я просто высказал своё отношение, которое, конечно же, может и измениться.

Comment: *К Вам могу и по имени — когда-то ведь Вы дали на это добро.* Да, конечно, для меня приятнее всего, когда ко мне по имени обращаются. Но вот Вы меня пугаете немного: я не жду разрешения на то, чтобы обращаться по имени, а судя по Вашим рассуждениям кому-то это может не нравиться...

Comment: Римма Михайлова: _"В полном академическом справочнике (Особенности написания отдельных суффиксов. § 45):
<...> тундреный <...> тундреная <...> где как исключение в суффиксе пишется одно **н**."_ === Написание изменено. Сейчас правильно писать это слово с двумя "н": **тундренный**.См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x

Comment: Спасибо за информацию — не только для меня, но и для **всех.**

Comment: Я дала ссылку на Лопатина, собственно, только для того, чтобы было понятно: слово "ветреный" относится к исключениям. Их обычно и фиксируют орфографические словари. Разве не так?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой,по-моему, вы/Вы(как вам угодно)  слишком критичны. Прочитайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: ***Вопросы «Справочному бюро»***

                                                                                                                                              Можно ли при обращении к одному человеку писать вы, ваш с маленькой буквы?

Употребление местоимения вы вместо ты при обращении к одному лицу само по себе уже представляет проявление уважительного отношения к этому лицу. Окончательное решение о написании Вы с прописной (для подчеркивания этого уважительного отношения) принимает автор текста.

Comment: И еще:  http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=8.24

Comment: @Серж: ссылка не открывается, Серж! В каком смысле слишком критичен? (Вы обращались ко мне с маленькой буквы и меня это вполне устраивает, я сделал вывод, что и вы не против того же к себе. Или нет? Так же и с behemothus-ом. При этом я ни к вам двоим, ни к другим в подобных случаях не отношусь с меньшим уважением, просто проще, удобнее так писать.)

Comment: Конечно не против! Обращение на вы само по себе знак уважения. А критичен в том, что думаете, к незнакомцам нельзя обращаться на вы, а мы между собой можем. Кстати, не думаю, что кто-нибудь из нас( постоянных участников) будет против обращения на вы.

Comment: Странно! У меня открывается. Там вы найдете  ответы на все интересующие вас вопросы по поводу написания Вы/вы.

Comment: *Кстати, не думаю, что кто-нибудь из нас (постоянных участников) будет против обращения на вы.* Именно с маленькой, да? Да я бы с радостью упростил, но вдруг кому-то не понравится?

Comment: А вообще, большое спасибо, Серж, что подключились к обсуждению и сказали своё мнение! Давно вас вообще не слышно было. ;)

Comment: @Серж: *Странно! У меня открывается.* О, теперь с компьютера открылось (с телефона не получалось)!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой "Грамма" (вернее её хостер) почему-то не любит некоторых провайдеров. Я просто поменял прокси - и вошел. Что до самой заметки, которую Серж подсунул (*по своей привычке подносить грамму как истину в последней инстанции?*), то она меня не впечатлила. Столь маститому языковеду как Светлана Викторовна стоит хотя бы знать, что "масленый" - это вообще из "другой оперы" оно подпадает под общее правило,  а правильный примером "еще одного исключения" будет, например "тундреный" - вот уж это слово никак не объяснить "по Далю", глагола "тундрить" нет и никогда в природе не существовало.

Comment: @behemothus, я не подношу Грамму, как истинуу в последней инстанции, я просто ссылаюсь на нее, зная, что там можно найти ответ. В истинности материалах которых сомневаетесь только вы.

Comment: Светлана Викторовна лишь говорит о том, что прилагательное ветреный, как и прилагательное масленый образовано от глагола несовершенного вида, а следовательно попадает под общее правило.

Comment: @Серж *Светлана Викторовна лишь говорит...*  - я сам в состоянии прочесть то, на что вы дали ссылку. .Или Вы хотите сказать, что про "масленый" в заметке нет?  ))))

Comment: Еще раз повторяю, пример с "масленый" - не в тему. Есть реальные примеры, которые СВ просто проигнорировала. ***Тундреный, выдреный*** (при нормативном "бедренный") и проч.- вот что Д-Д обошла стороной. А "масленый" не вызывает никаких сомнений.

Comment: Я лишь говорю о том, что ветреный образовано по той же модели, что и масленый. И лингвист лишь об этом говорит. И все. Все в тему.

Comment: @Серж *Я лишь говорю о том, что ветреный образовано по той же модели* А я о том, что говорит Дуговейко-Должанская. Статью Д-Д я прокомментировал. В чем проблема?!

Comment: Проблема в том, что ваши комментарии в адрес статьи  С.В. неуместны. Потому, что ничем не обоснованы.